# angular-input-modified - setting form prestine

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using an angular form which edits data. The data is fetched by $http and assigned to a controller object. I see that the form is set to modified due to this data assignment. I would like to have form state as not modified. This is being done on a button click, i would rather do it $http.success. this does not seem to be working though. Can you please advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did the delayed initialization as shown at http://betsol.github.io/angular-input-modified/delayed-init/

Here is my code.

```
$http({
    ...
    ...
}).success(function(rdata, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.user = angular.copy(rdata.data);
    // Calling set-pristine after digest cycle.
    if ($scope.myProfileForm) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.myProfileForm.$setPristine();
        });
    }
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    ...
    ...
});
```